# I have a problem with my A/C Econ light

Tags: ac

2006 Audi A4 Quattro 3.0ltr V6 diesel, ECON light comes ON and after a while switches off by itself, and whilst is OFF by pressing the button it does not switch off. Is it connected to loss of power whilst it is on.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/36548/4152) answer things for you?